# Can not import matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I get the error NotImplementedError: Implement enable_gui in a subclass when trying to import matplotlib in vscode. Below is the full traceback. I am not sure what is the problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/josecordova/opt/anaconda3/envs/Research/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Users/josecordova/opt/anaconda3/envs/Research/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/josecordova/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1060902895/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/Users/josecordova/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1060902895/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "/Users/josecordova/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1060902895/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "/Users/josecordova/opt/anaconda3/envs/Research/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/Users/josecordova/opt/anaconda3/envs/Research/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/Users/josecordova/opt/anaconda3/envs/Research/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/josecordova/Desktop/Michigan/sociallearning/dominance.py", line 11, in <module>
    for filename in os.listdir('/Users/josecordova/Desktop/Michigan/sociallearning/LRPM_LR'):
  File "/Users/josecordova/Desktop/Michigan/sociallearning/dominance.py", line 11, in <module>
    for filename in os.listdir('/Users/josecordova/Desktop/Michigan/sociallearning/LRPM_LR'):
  File "/Users/josecordova/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1060902895/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 945, in trace_dispatch
    self.do_wait_suspend(thread, frame, event, arg)
  File "/Users/josecordova/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1060902895/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 164, in do_wait_suspend
    self._args[0].do_wait_suspend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/josecordova/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1060902895/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1949, in do_wait_suspend
    keep_suspended = self._do_wait_suspend(thread, frame, event, arg, suspend_type, from_this_thread, frames_tracker)
  File "/Users/josecordova/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1060902895/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1971, in _do_wait_suspend
    self._activate_mpl_if_needed()
  File "/Users/josecordova/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1060902895/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1516, in _activate_mpl_if_needed
    activate_function()
  File "/Users/josecordova/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1060902895/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1505, in <lambda>
    self.mpl_modules_for_patching = {"matplotlib": lambda: activate_matplotlib(do_enable_gui),
  File "/Users/josecordova/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1060902895/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydev_ipython/matplotlibtools.py", line 95, in activate_matplotlib
    gui, backend = find_gui_and_backend()
  File "/Users/josecordova/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1060902895/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydev_ipython/matplotlibtools.py", line 47, in find_gui_and_backend
    backend = matplotlib.rcParams['backend']
  File "/Users/josecordova/opt/anaconda3/envs/Research/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 831, in __getitem__
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "/Users/josecordova/opt/anaconda3/envs/Research/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2362, in <module>
    install_repl_displayhook()
  File "/Users/josecordova/opt/anaconda3/envs/Research/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 126, in install_repl_displayhook
    ip.enable_gui(ipython_gui_name)
  File "/Users/josecordova/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3470, in enable_gui
    raise NotImplementedError('Implement enable_gui in a subclass')
NotImplementedError: Implement enable_gui in a subclass
```

Comment: You've only provided the stack-trace - where's the code?

Comment: It happens when importing, even if there is no more code. just the import matplotlib line

Comment: Same error in the Python CLI?